# After uninstalling Conda 3.8 cmd became unavailable

Tags: cmd, conda

## Overview

I uninstalled Conda and it broke cmd. I am unable to start cmd and I also get an error when opening a PS terminal. When I installed Conda I ran `conda init` for ps and cmd. I would like to reverse the effect of this command. I no longer have conda and so cannot use that.

## Powershell behaviour:

> conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the  spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - conda init --reverse
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException      
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

## Cmd behaviour:

Doesn't open, brief flash of a window.

Comment: what does the error say

Answer (score 2):

## Resolution

In the registry, there is a key; `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\autorun` with the value set to `if exists`. I removed that key's value. **If you have a statement that runs batch scripts, don't just bin it**.

## What is this key?

According to [this resource](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/registry/tree/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Command-Processor/index) the key is used to run batch scripts prior to opening cmd.

## Why?

`if exist` was evaluating to **false** and that blocked cmd from starting. I tested with a dummy expression `if exist 1=1` which led to cmd starting.

## Culprit

This happened when **uninstalling Conda 3.8**.